# What is wrong with this C++ exception syntax (std::runtime_error)?

Tags: c++

What is wrong with the use of `std::range_error` below? 
When I compile this code I get a

```
"syntax error :';'"
```

( btw I understand that the exception specification of a function is now ignored, but is that causing the syntax error? )

```
#include <stdexcept>

void function() throw(std::runtime_error) {
  if(true)
    throw (std::range_error);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range_error` is a type. To throw one, you need to create an object:

```
throw std::range_error("Your message goes here");
```

You can use the type name as you do in the function's exception specifier; but you shouldn't since they're deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 problems...

- You need to `#include <stdexcept>`
- `std::range_error` constructor requires a string argument

Answer (score 0):

There are two uses of `throw`:

1. As a declaration. The syntax is `throw(<exception specification>)`.
2. As a statement. The syntax is `throw exception_object;`.

Your code is attempting to use both, but the syntax of the second is wrong.

In an unrelated matter, exception specification declarations have fallen out of favour since they offer comparatively little benefit, are confusing to many users (since they do *not* offer compile-time checks) and have a better replacement in C++11.